# Module for displaying and altering ethernet interfaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking

I need to display and alter the ethernet interfaces on an embedded linux board. E.g. for eth0, wlan0, I need to get and set ipaddresses, masks, dhcp, ssid etc.

Before I go of and write my own thing (eg by parsing `/etc/network/interfaces`, running `nmcli` etc), I was wondering if there existed a module that did much of this already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `wmi` module. [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) is the link.